# What is the Vb.net version of (c#)Cast?

Tags: vb.net

How do I convert the following line into VB.net??

```
FtpWebRequest uploadRequest =(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("example.com" + @"/" + "localfile.html");
```

Comment: Always use "example.com".  See RFC2606 http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim uploadRequest As FtpWebRequest = 
  DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("example.com/localfile.html"), FtpWebRequest)
```

For future reference, you could just put your code into a [C# to VB.NET code converter.](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Also I'm not sure what you're doing with website.com. Is that a string? (It's not a valid variable name if thats what its suppose to be).

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim uploadRequest As FtpWebRequest = 
  CType(WebRequest.Create("example.com/localfile.html"), FtpWebRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim uploadRequest as FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(
    WebRequest.Create(websitecom & "/localfile.html", FtpWebRequest)
```

I'm assuming websitecom is a variable and if that's the case then the "." shouldn't be in it.  If it was supposed to be a string then just put it inside the quotations.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a plus sign before localfile.html:

Dim uploadRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(website.com + "/" + "localfile.html"), FtpWebRequest)